# How do I apply same color palette to dendrogram and scatterplot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot, dendrogram

I am making a dendrogram plot and a scatterplot from the same data, both plotted with `ggplot2`.  I use `as.dendrogram()` to convert the `hclust()` object into a form suitable for `ggplot()`, then set branch and label colors using the `set()` function from `dendextend`. I use `metaMDS()` and `scores()` from `vegan` for the MNDS results. I color the points in the NMDS scatterplot based on groups created by `dendextend::cutree()`. I use the same color palette to color the branches and labels in dendrogram.

However, the colors of the groups do not match between the two plots. I assumed because I applied the same colors to the dendrogram and scatterplot, and used the groups from `cutree` to inform the scatterplot that I would get the same color groups.

**How can I ensure that both plots use the same colors for the same groups?**

Notice in the images below that Milan, Barcelona, and Marseille (for one example) are one color in the dendrogram and another color in the scatterplot. In the dendrogram, Barcelona is assigned the fourth color from the palette but it is assigned to group 2 from cutree and thus gets the second color from the palette.

Dendrogram
[image]

NMDS scatterplot
[image]

**MWE**

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dendextend)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(vegan)

kay <- 5
mycolors <- brewer.pal(kay, "Dark2")

euro.hc <- hclust(eurodist)
euro.cut <- dendextend::cutree(euro.hc, k = kay)

euro.nmds <- metaMDS(eurodist, k = kay)

euro.df <- scores(euro.nmds, display = "sites", tidy = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(grp = as.factor(euro.cut))

dend <- as.dendrogram(euro.hc) %>%
  set("branches_k_color",
    value = mycolors,
    k = kay
  ) %>%
  set("labels_colors",
    value = mycolors,
    k = kay
  ) %>%
  set("branches_lwd", 1.0) %>%
  set("labels_cex", 1)


dend %>% ggplot(horiz = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(-1, -1)) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(1, 1)) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  )

euro.df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, color = grp)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, label = label, color = grp),
    vjust = -1,
    hjust = .50
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = mycolors, guide = NULL) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    line = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank()
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I finally figured out a solution. It works well but seems "hacky" so I would like to learn if there is a better/more efficient method.

Here's a summary of the changes. The full working code and output are included below.

1. Set `order_clusters_as_data = FALSE` in `cutree()`
2. Get the names from `cutree()` and the branch and label colors via `get_leaves_branches_col`
3. Create a temporary dataframe from these two vectors.
4. Make the main dataframe after the making the dendrogram.
5. Left join the temporary dataframe to my main data frame.
6. Move color outside of `aes()` and take it from the colr column of the dataframe.

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dendextend)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(vegan)

kay <- 5
mycolors <- brewer.pal(kay, "Dark2")

euro.hc <- hclust(eurodist)
euro.cut <- dendextend::cutree(euro.hc, k = kay, order_clusters_as_data = FALSE)

euro.nmds <- metaMDS(eurodist, k = kay)

dend <- as.dendrogram(euro.hc) %>%
  set("branches_k_color",
    value = mycolors,
    k = kay
  ) %>%
  set("labels_colors",
    value = mycolors,
    k = kay
  ) %>%
  set("branches_lwd", 1.0) %>%
  set("labels_cex", 1)

label <- names(euro.cut)
colr <- get_leaves_branches_col(dend)
tmp.df <- data.frame(label = label, colr = colr) #order = order
euro.df <- scores(euro.nmds, display = "sites", tidy = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(x = ., y = tmp.df, by = "label")


dend %>% ggplot(horiz = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(-1, -1)) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(1, 1)) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  )

euro.df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2), 
             color = euro.df$colr) +
  geom_text(aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, label = label),
    color = euro.df$colr,
    vjust = -1,
    hjust = .50
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = mycolors, guide = NULL) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    line = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>